# Opening multiple associated files at once with Electron when app is not started

Tags: electron

Let me start out by explaining the scenario. Our Electron app is set to be a single instance. I have files associated in windows that are set to open our Electron app. Double clicking on an associated file works fantastic.  It opens the app and the app opens the file and all is well.  Doing the same if the app is open also works great.  It loads the file and all is good. The app stays a single instance and the files are opened as they should be.

The issue comes when I select multiple associated files (when the app is closed) and right click and select 'open'.  Only one of the multiple files will be loaded.  It seems to swallow the command line calls for the other files.

This does not happen if the app is already open however.  If the app is open, it receives all of the commands and will open each file.

I am wondering if the issue is the way I have the app set up for singular instance, but I honestly don't know.

Here is the code that I have set up for singular instance:

```
const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();

if (!gotTheLock) {
  app.quit();
} else {
  app.on('second-instance', (event, argv, workingDirectory) => {

    // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
    if (main) {
      if (main.isMinimized()) main.restore();
      main.focus();
      if (argv.length >= 3) {
        let fileArray = [,,...argv]
        main.webContents.send('open-files-selected', fileArray);
      }
    }
  });
  app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
   });
 }
```

In my CreateWindow I have the following to get the command parameters to open the file:

```
 if (process.argv.length >= 2) {
      let fileArray = [,...process.argv]
      main.webContents.send('open-files-selected', fileArray);
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.